# 500 error on Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, campaign-member

Here is the code on my cloud page.  I'm a trying to change the status of a campaign member to Responded if they click on the RSVP button in an email.  I am getting a 500 error.  Does anyone see anything wrong with my code?

```
%%[

var @FirstName, @CampaignMemberID, @status

set @FirstName = RequestParameter('First Name')

set @CampaignMemberID = RequestParameter('CampaignMemberID')

/* on page load */

set @status = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('CampaignMember',@CampaignMemberID,'Status','Responded')
]%%

%%First Name%%

Thank you for registering for our event, looking forward to seeing you there.
```

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it and I'm still getting a 500 error.  I thought I must be doing something stupid wrong but if I take out all the code and only leave the text it works.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Updated my answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding some debugging statements to see what's not getting populated before you add in your `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject()` function:

```
%%[

var @FirstName, @CampaignMemberID, @status

set @FirstName = RequestParameter('First Name')

set @CampaignMemberID = RequestParameter('CampaignMemberID')

output(concat("<br>FirstName: ", @FirstName))
output(concat("<br>CampaignMemberID: ", @CampaignMemberID))

/* on page load */

/*
 set @status = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('CampaignMember',@CampaignMemberID,'Status','Responded') 
 */
]%%

%%=v(@firstName)=%%

Thank you for registering for our event, looking forward to seeing you there.
```

**Update**

You probably should be using [**QueryParameter()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/queryparameter.htm) instead of [**RequestParameter()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) if you're just retrieving URL parameters by name:

```
%%[

var @FirstName, @CampaignMemberID, @status

set @FirstName = QueryParameter('First Name')

set @CampaignMemberID = QueryParameter('CampaignMemberID')

output(concat("<br>FirstName: ", @FirstName))
output(concat("<br>CampaignMemberID: ", @CampaignMemberID))

/* on page load */

/*
 set @status = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('CampaignMember',@CampaignMemberID,'Status','Responded') 
 */
]%%

%%=v(@firstName)=%%
```

Comment: Something worked!! The results were: FirstName: 
CampaignMemberID:   Is this what I was expecting back? Field names but no data?

Comment: Nope, you were supposed to get field values too.  This indicates that issues lies with the original page load.